# How can I monitor input on a USB port in Windows?

Tags: python, c++, usb

Short version: How do I monitor a USB port's input?

Long version: I wanted to use a console controller for my pc games, but couldn't find a freeware method of doing so that I liked. So I decided to make one myself, as much as a learning exercise as anything else, but I'm not sure how to monitor input on a USB port. I assume that if I can monitor one, it won't be hard to experimentally determine what each input is (A button = 00011 etc) on the keyboard, mouse and controller and then just convince the computer that the controller is a keyboard/mouse by switching whatever is inputted by it to what would have been inputted by one of the other devices.

I tried Google, but no luck. Same with this site. I know some C, C++ and Python but I wouldn't call myself a power user of any of them, part of the reason I'm doing this really. Currently using Windows Vista and Windows 10. Any help getting started would be appreciated.

Comment: "*I assume that if I can monitor one, it won't be hard to experimentally determine what each input is (A button = 00011 etc) on the keyboard*" ... that is a very bold statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pyusb` and you will find examples on how to communicate with USB devices. It seems that the current repository is at GitHub: https://github.com/walac/pyusb